# How to convert Any type data into Double

Tags: xcode, swift5

This's the last part my assignment, I've tried all methods I could came up, but still not going through this.

Dictionary's are still not yet taught, so I think I just don't know syntax, but as I do have come up a way to solve it, then I guess, I'm not cheating.

From the first loop, I can access all gpa data. However, in the second loop, it says  binary operator '>' cannot be applied to 'Any' operand
Therefore, if there's any syntax to convert Any type of data into Double, I think my problem's solved.

```
var students : [[String:Any]] =
[[ "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Wilson", "gpa": 2.4 ], [
"firstName": "Nancy", "lastName": "Smith", "gpa": 3.5 ], [
"firstName": "Michael", "lastName": "Liu", "gpa": 3.1 ]]

var currentHighest : Any = 0.0

for person in students{

    print(person["gpa"]!)
}

for person in students{

    var  grade:Any = person["gpa"]!

   if(grade > currentHighest){
       currentHighest = grade
   }
}

print(currentHighest)
```

Answer (score 0):

`currentHighest` is not `Any`, it's `Double` so declare it as `Double`, remove the annotation

```
var currentHighest = 0.0
```

And in the loop cast the value to `Double`

```
for person in students {

   let grade = person["gpa"] as! Double

   if grade > currentHighest {
       currentHighest = grade
   }
}
```

---

A custom struct is still more efficient

```
struct Person {
    let firstName, lastName : String
    let gpa : Double
}

let students = [Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Wilson", gpa: 2.4),
                Person(firstName: "Nancy", lastName: "Smith", gpa: 3.5),
                Person(firstName: "Michael", lastName: "Liu", gpa: 3.1)]

let currentHighest = students.map{$0.gpa}.max()!
print(currentHighest)
```